# MySQL query works on its own but not as an IN subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
    nav_foreign_port_view
WHERE
    country_code IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            country_code
        FROM
            carrier_regions cr,
            carrier_region_associate cra
        WHERE
            SCAC = 'SUDU'
                AND cra.region_id = cr.region_id)
ORDER BY city_name ASC , country_name ASC;
```

When I run it I get the message

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'country_code' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'
```

However, when I run the IN subquery on its own it works fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: Is `country_code ` in `nav_foreign_port_view` ? I think not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a column named `country_code` in `nav_foreign_port_view`.